# cakephp savemany validation

Tags: validation, cakephp, save, cakephp-2.1

i have array with valid and not valid values , i want to save valid values with saveMany method , but if this method validate all value in array its work and save my data Otherwise its not working !

my array :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'product_id' => '3',
        'factor_id' => '2',
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'product_id' => '1',
        'factor_id' => '2',
    )
)
```

my code :

```
$this->Basket->saveMany($newBasket);
//or
$this->Basket->saveMany($newBasket,array('validate' => true));
```

thanks

Comment: You want it to save records that are valid and discard any records that have validation errors?

Answer (score 2):

my answer is :

> $this->ModelName->saveMany($data,array('validate'=>'only','atomic'=>false));

thanks all

Comment: Can you please say the use of 'atomic'=>false, clearly? @ali786